# Searching multiple list an updating fields in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 3 list of items that are going to be used to update objects in another list.

```
public class Item1
{
   public string A
   public string B
   public string C
   public string D
   public string E
}

public class Item2
{
   public string A
   public string B
   public string D
   public string E
}

public class Item3
{
   public string A
   public string C
   public string D
   public string E
}

public class ObjectToUpdate
{
   public string A
   public string B
   public string C
   public string D
   public string E
}
```

What is the fastest way to update the list of objects with this criteria?

If A, B, C from object match A,B,C in Item1 set D and E equal to D and E from item  1.

else if A, B from object  match A,B in Item2 set D and E equal to D and E from item  2.

else if A, C from object  match A,C in Item3 set D and E equal to D and E from item  3.

All of these are in list.

```
List<Item1> list1
List<Item2> list2
List<Item3> list3
List<ObjectToUpdate> objectsToUpdate
```

Added attempt:

```
        foreach (var item in objectsToUpdate)
        {
            var a = list1.FirstOrDefault(l => l.A == item.A && l.B== item.B && l.C== item.C);

            if(a != null)
            {
                item.D= a.D;
                item.E= a.E;
            }
            else
            {
                var b = list2.FirstOrDefault(l => l.A == item.A && l.B == item.B);

                if(b != null)
                {
                    item.D= b.D;
                    item.E= b.E;
                }
                else
                {
                    var c = list3.FirstOrDefault(l => l.A == item.A && l.C == item.C);

                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        item.D= c.D;
                        item.E= c.E;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's your current attempt?

Comment: Assuming the keys in each list are unique, and the lists are large enough that the overhead isn't significant, use LINQ `ToDictionary` to create three dictionaries for each list/key set and then use `TryGetValue` to check for each match in order.

Comment: The strange thing about your questions though is.  In the lists, you can have many records that have the same required properties to change the "objectsToUpdate".  So say if you had 5 records in list 1 that pass the conditional, they will all update the objectsToUpdate list.  So objectsToUpdate will only retain the D and E value from the final record from list 1.  You get what I mean?  So what you might want to do is add every record to objectsToUpdate instead of changing their records over and over again, so you retain all the D and E values from all the other lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (var item in objectsToUpdate)
            {
                var a = list1.Where(l => l.A == item.A && l.B == item.B && l.C == item.C).ToList();

                if(a != null)
                {
                    foreach(var x in a)
                    {
                       item.D = x.D;
                       item.E = x.E;
                    }
                }


                var b = list2.Where(l => l.A == item.A && l.B == item.B).ToList();

                if(b != null)
                {
                    foreach(var x in b)
                    {
                       item.D = x.D;
                       item.E = x.E;
                    }

                }


                var c = list3.Where(l => l.A == item.A && l.C == item.C).ToList();

                if (c != null)
                {
                    foreach(var x in c)
                    {
                       item.D = x.D;
                       item.E = x.E;
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Do you see why I am making a, b and c lists instead of your first or default?  Its because there can be many records with that property and you want to alter all of the records with that property to have a new x.D and x.E

Comment: I just edited because I had the setting the other way around.  Now your setting the objectsToUpdate with x.D and x.E.  Should be all good now.